# How to remove outer layer margin from MDTextField?

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I want to have two MDTextFields touching each other at their bottom and top border

The MDTextField has an outer layer which prevents them from touching each other. Is there a property to remove this margin? Margins I want to remove(black rectangles):

[MDTextfields colored to show the margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VvN8.png)

Lines I want to touch:

[Arrows pointing at parts of borders I want to merge together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmLaY.png)

```
   BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size_hint: 1, None
        height:textfield1.height+ textfield2.height
        MDTextField:
            id:textfield1
            hint_text: "Rectangle mode"
            mode: "rectangle"
        MDTextField:

            id:textfield2
            hint_text: "Rectangle mode"
            mode: "rectangle"
```

Final product would be something like this:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmAdh.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment due to rep. This worked for me:

spacing:"-10dp" in BoxLayout